# Ordenação crescente de colunas, mas por linha de resultado

Tags: sql, sql-server

tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabela e resultados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso criar uma instrução eficiente capaz de ordenar os valores na forma crescente, porém devem ser ordenados por coluna/linha e não somente por coluna.

No caso do exemplo acima, o resultado esperado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.
Obrigado.

Comment: Mostre a estrutura da tabela , uma dica inicial seria montar um "unpivot" da colunas em linhas , ordená-las e depois ordenar esta saída.  https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Você tem que ler a linha ordenar os valores  linha a linha, faça por parte, e use um loop para navegar entre cada linha.

Comment: Um "unpivot" pode ser feito tambem por union select col1 from tabela union select col2 from tabela ...

Comment: Fiz algumas instruções via loop, porém não ficou tão prático. Acredito que exista uma forma melhor para fazer isso. Vou pesquisar a respeito de "unpivot". Obrigado senhores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei um meio eficiente de fazer com que as colunas fiquem ordenadas de acordo com os valores apresentados nas linhas.

Desde já agradeço ao Motta por ter sugerido o estudo do "unpivot/pivot".

Abaixo deixo o código da criação da tabela de acordo com os dados apresentados na pergunta:

```
create table TabelaTeste
(
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int,
    Col3 int,
    Col4 int
)

insert into TabelaTeste
select 18, 20, 25, 23
union
select 23, 15, 5, 4
union
select 20, 23, 12, 8
union
select 16, 5, 25, 24
```

E a resolução para que seja feita a ordenação crescente dos valores de acordo com coluna/linha.

```
--Recupera o número da linha
--Pode ser utilizado para conferência dos valores
; with numerado as
(
   select *,
         row_number() over (order by (select null)) NumeroLinha
   from TabelaTeste
),
-- Cria a ordenação desejada
-- dentro de um "unpivoted data"
ordenado as
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by NumeroLinha order by v asc) nl from numerado 
 -- Informe as colunas desejadas aqui
 unpivot (v for c in (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)) u
)
-- Retorna os dados no novo layout
select NumeroLinha,
       [1] Col1,
       [2] Col2,
       [3] Col3,
       [4] Col4
  from 
  (    
    select NumeroLinha,
           v,
           Nl
      from ordenado
  ) o
 pivot (min(v) for Nl in ([1], [2], [3], [4])) p
```

Comment: Eu gosto quando a pessoa que entrou com a dúvida "acha" a solução, esta eu até vou guardar pois posso precisar uma dia ...

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica Motta. Abraços.